# Обращение к n-ому cимволу в строки в массиве строк

Tags: c++

Допустим есть массив str[100], как допустим вывести на экран n символ i строки?

```
int main()
{
    string s[100];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> s[i];
    }

    string lines;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = 0;
        string lines = s[i];
        cout <<< lines[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: Мало информации что значит массив строк

    char[][], char*[],char**, string[], string*, vector<string>,        vector<char>, list<char>, char*, собственный класс и.т.д. и.т.п. 

C каждым из этих типов все это делается по разному.
P.S. в С++ можно очень легко выстрелить себе в ногу.

Comment: str[100] - это, тащемта, имя буфера, например. А надо полную сигнатуру, например.

Comment: А что делает вот этот код?

> cout <<< lines[n];

Comment: Для std::string перегружено [] вроде поэтому cout << имя_строки[i][n]; должно сработать

Comment: так и писал раньше... не работает ну или я кривой)

Comment: 1) cout <<< lines[n]; - как думаешь, где ошибка?)
2) а зачем ты переопределяешь lines?
3) что за бестиповая переменная с, которая инициализируется нулем?
И код вообще совершенно не то, что ты хочешь - в итоге ты выведешь n первых элементов, а не i элементов n-ой строки...

Answer (score 3):

Вывод n-ого элемента i-ой строки для массива `std::string s[100]`:

```
cout<<s[i][n];
```

Строка типа `std::string` - это, собственно, массив символов, поэтому работаем как с двумерным массивом.

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно пробежаться по массиву и искать переносы на следующую строчку.
Как только нашлось (i-1) перенос строки, то вы оказались на i-ой строке. Дальше просто выводите n символов
При выводе нужно следить за тем, чтобы в строке было n символов (чтобы на след строчку не вылезти)

как-то так)

Comment: ну я писал так
string line;
for (int i:=0;i<n;i++);i// количество строк
{line=s[i];
cout <<line[n];
}
к сожелению не работает(

Comment: ты свой код выложи, проще будет о нему что-то сказать..

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю, а в чём проблема сначала обратиться к нужному элементу массива и затем вызвать функцию at(int n)?